# magento email not sending when moved to server

Tags: magento-1.7

I have developed a site using magento in my localhost and the mails are sending as required. When I moved to the server no emails are send. I have checked the server side by placing test.php in the root directory with content:  . The mail was sent for this. Please any one could help me..

Answer (score 0):

try SMTP Pro Email - Free Custom SMTP Email module. Can find it in magentoconnect